# I cant reclaim back my lumens,inflation lumens problems

Tags: accounts, ledger, wallets, inflation, lumens

I sign with my ledger , but somehow my ledger account created new account and sends my lumens
how can I reclaim back my Lumens
thank you

" GD32…XF5T created account GAOI…5MKK with starting balance 146,555 XLM. "

Answer (score 1):

We got scammed...it was via a email from coin desk leading to a sneaky copy website of stellar account...
This is real: https://accountviewer.stellar.org/#!/
This is the scammer fake one which has a .sb added to it....stellarr.org.sb/#!/**